# Mandrill-Error code-5 while sending email template through Java

Tags: java, mandrill

I am using mandrill api to send Template emails in java but I am Getting Following Error:

> com.cribbstechnologies.clients.mandrill.exception.RequestFailedException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500 {"status":"error","code":5,"name":"Unknown_Template","message":"No such template \"Hello\""}

my Code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        config.setApiKey("Your_Api_Key");
        config.setApiVersion("1.0");
        config.setBaseURL("https://mandrillapp.com/api");

        request.setConfig(config);
        request.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        messagesRequest.setRequest(request);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        request.setHttpClient(client);

        //MandrillMessageRequest mmr = new MandrillMessageRequest();
        MandrillHtmlMessage message = new MandrillHtmlMessage();
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("X-MC-TrackingDomain", "http://executeproject.com:8585/OctopusMailTest/track?cmpid=1");
        message.setFrom_email("noreply@octopusmail.com");
        message.setFrom_name("Anand");
        message.setHeaders(headers);
        //message.setHtml("<html><body><h1>Please Open this mail and click any where.i will track your click.</h1>Don't wait click google?<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a></body></html>");
        message.setSubject("Good Afternoon !");

        MandrillRecipient[] recipients = new MandrillRecipient[]{new MandrillRecipient("anand","anandkumar.m@softidsolutions.com"), new MandrillRecipient("rakesh","rakesh.s@softidsolutions.com"),new MandrillRecipient("Ravi","ravi.k@softidsolutions.com")};
        message.setTo(recipients);
        /*message.setTrack_clicks(true);
        message.setTrack_opens(true);*/
        //mmr.setMessage(message);


        MandrillTemplatedMessageRequest mtmr=new MandrillTemplatedMessageRequest();
        mtmr.setTemplate_name("Hello");
        TemplateContent template=new TemplateContent();
        List<TemplateContent>template_content=new ArrayList<TemplateContent>();
        template.setName("First Block");
        template.setContent("<h1>Helllo You are in First Block<br/>");
        template_content.add(template);
        template.setName("Second Block");
        template.setContent("<h1>Helllo You are in Second Block");
        template_content.add(template);
        mtmr.setTemplate_content(template_content);
        mtmr.setMessage(message);
        try {
            messagesRequest.sendTemplatedMessage(mtmr);
            //SendMessageResponse response = messagesRequest.sendMessage(mmr);
            System.out.println("Message sent Successfully");

        } catch (RequestFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually [added](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582507-Getting-Started-with-Templates/) *and* published the template in your Mandrill account yet?

Comment: i want to add Template through API call. Not added in Mandrill account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
MandrillApi mandrillApi = new MandrillApi("<Mandrill API here>");
MandrillTemplate newTemplate = mandrillApi.templates().add(
    "test_template_001", 
    "<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>",
    false);
```